# Backbone.js - data not being populated in collection even though fetch is successful

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am trying to populate a collection from a simple JSON file as part of learning  backbone.js. But I can't get it to work.

The AJAX call is made (verified with FireBug), but the `toJSON` method returns  `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
theModel =  Backbone.Model.extend();

theCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: aModel,
    url: "source.json"
});

theView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $("#temp"),
   initialize: function () {
       this.collection = new theCollection();
       this.collection.fetch();
       this.render();
   },
   render : function () {
       $(this.el).html( this.collection.toJSON() ); // Returns blank
   }
});

var myView = new theView;
```

Here's my JSON:

```
[{
    "description": "Lorem ipsum..."
 },
 {
    "description": "Lorem ipsum..."
}]
```

Comment: Did you realize `fetch()` is asynchronous?

Comment: No, didn't know that. Should I call `render()` as an  callback then?

Comment: See above - changed it with a callback

Comment: I'm curious too. My first instinct is to bind to the collection's `reset` event to render the view. I'm curious what SO thinks...

Comment: Uh, you've totally affected the answer to your question. Now you just have a `this` problem. If I were you I'd revert the change, the original problem is more interesting.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what to do really. It seems now that the `render()` is never called what so ever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fetch` is asynchronous, your collection won't yet be populated if you immediately call `render`. To solve this problem, you just have to bind the collection *reset* event (*sync* event for Backbone>=1.0) to the view render :

```
theView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $("#temp"),

   initialize: function () {
       this.collection = new theCollection();

       // for Backbone < 1.0
       this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);

       // for Backbone >= 1.0
       this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this);

       this.collection.fetch();
   },

   render : function () {
    console.log( this.collection.toJSON() );
   }
});
```

Note the third argument of the bind method, giving the correct context to the method:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer to my question. That third argument is completely new to me. I guess that it's the same as doing `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` or just `_.bindAll(this);` to get the `this` available in all methods?

Comment: Mostly, this syntax only binds the render method to this on reset events, whereas _.bindAll(this, 'render') bind render to this for all calls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am starting to get a hang of the difference of binding `this` and binding events now :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe the problem lies in your json

either you override the parse method on the collection, to work with your json

or you could change the json :)

```
[{
    "description": "Lorem ipsum..."
},
{
    "description": "Lorem ipsum..."
}]
```

i believe this is what your json should look like, just an array of your models.

Comment: Hi Sander. Thanks for that. I had mistyped the JSON here, so unfortunately it wasn't that easy :)