# each() function is not defined on this.collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to make ajax request to server. I am using `fetch()` method on collection. It successfully retrieves data from server after monitoring google chrome network tab.

Here is scenario.

I have `Model` below

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/contacts',
});
```

`collection` below

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,
    url: '/contacts'
});
```

`ViewOne` below

```
var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var collection = new Collection().fetch(); // also tried with these options { wait:true, reset: true, async: false }
        new ViewTwo({ collection: collection });
    }
});
```

Below is `ViewTwo`

```
var ViewTwo = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.each(this.render, this); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.model);
    }
});
```

As you can see I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

`this.render` exist so that is not a problem. The problem is each function on `this.collection`. **How can I solve this proble?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone API is not fluent, which means that [`Collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) does not return itself, it returns the Ajax object used in `fetch`.

Try

```
var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var collection = new Collection();
        collection.fetch();

        new ViewTwo({ collection: collection });
    }
});
```

And note that the `collection.fetch` is asynchronous, `this.collection` will be probably empty in `ViewTwo.initialize`. See [Backbone.js - data not being populated in collection even though fetch is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413500/backbone-js-populating-a-collection/8415515#8415515) for example.

Answer (score 2):

simply create new view in success callback of fetch

```
var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var collection = new Collection();
        collection.fetch({
         success:function(){ 
            new ViewTwo({ collection: collection });
            }
             }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @undefinedcorvus create a fiddle to replicate the error